# Allure clean history

Tags: allure

I use allure for reporting testcafe. Everything is fine expect the allure usage. How I can clean up allure reports from old data? In the documentation I read I have to use

```
allure report clean
```

I tried this command but allure do not understand, it expect another command.

Iam on macOS and I walk to the parent folder of allure-report. I expect from documentation that the command will select automatically the folder allure-report?

Anyone know how to clean up the allure report from old data by command line? I already cleaned up the folder allure-results.

For better understanding, I want to remove the old data from the generated report

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
allure generate --clean --output your-result-folder
```

Answer (score 1):

```
allure generate --clean
```

You will get this message
Report successfully generated to allure-report

Answer (score 0):

From the `allure` documentation:

Clean the report
If you want to remove the generated report data use allure report clean command.

By default the report commands will looking for the report in allure-results folder. If you are want to use the report from different location you can use -o option.

Please check the folder name where your reports are stored.

Comment: Iam with terminal inside folder "Testrunner". This contain a sub folder "allure-report". It also contain the folder "allure" with subfolder "allure-results". This folder is empty. So I expect the command will generate a empty allure-report.

Comment: Have you tried: `allure report clean -o allure-report`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a maven project, you can use this command :

```
mvn clean
```

The problem is that you are not removing the old executions from your `testNgresults.xml`